# Как собрать .apк файл в Qt Creator без эмулятора и установки на устройство

Tags: android, qt, qtcreator, apk

Мне нужно собрать android приложение в .apk файл, но у меня нет устройства с нужной архитектурой, а эмулятор не запускается(вылетает с ошибкой). На стадии Build apk файл не создается, создается он только на стадии Run, где требуется указать устройство для установки. Но мне не нужно ничего устанавливать, мне нужен лишь файл приложения, который я должен оправить другому человеку.

Comment: 1. Посмотри в разделе build, наверняка там заветная кнопка.  
2. Для разработки под android лучше всего Android Studio

Comment: для разработки на qt лучше подходит qt creator. надо бы разобраться почему билд не пашет. возможно нет нужного кросскомпилера